# How to make selective entire column absolute number

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make certain entire columns to be absolute whenever the start of the column detects Vbd.
However, the the argument is not optional error pops up at the part where i try to setcolumnname=last column in an attempt to convert number into column alphabet. Any help will be appreciated.

Updated Code Below:
[image]

```
    Option Explicit

Sub testing1()
Dim i As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim rngToAbs As Range
Dim lastrow As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
LastColumn = sht.Cells(1, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
 For i = 1 To LastColumn
     With sht
         If sht.Cells(1, i).Value = "Vbd" Then
             Set rngToAbs = .Range(sht.Cells(2, i), sht.Cells(lastrow, i))
             rngToAbs.Value = .Evaluate("=abs(" & rngToAbs.Address & ")")
         End If
     End With
 Next

End Sub
```

Before pressing the program
[image]

After pressing the program
[image]

In reality i want it to be 
[image]

Comment: You are setting your function `GetColumnName` to be a numeric value, so it nees to be `GetColumnName(25)` for example

Comment: Just use `Cells` and then you don't need to get the column letter.

Comment: What is `Vbd` in `If sht.Range("A1:LastColumn & 1") = Vbd`? And variables should not fall inside the quotes.

Comment: Yes, use `cells` or a single line like so `Function ColumnLetter(intColumn As Integer) As String
ColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, intColumn).Address, "$")(1)
End Function`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav hi all, i am trying to create the code in such a way that when the program runs, it will automatically detects the cell that has Vbd and convert that entire column into absolute instead of me trying to manually click that entire column to be absolute

Comment: You can't do `If sht.Range("A1:LastColumn & 1") = Vbd` - you can't compare a multi-cell range like that. You can only test one cell at a time.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav i didn't use cell because i didn't have the sufficient knowledge to do it in a way that i mentioned previously

Comment: @BigBen Ah i see, this is actually frustrating because i thought  that would work ;(

Comment: @BigBen is like im trying to scan that row for Vbd to make that column absolute if u get what i mean

Comment: What's the point of the `For j = 4 To LastColumn Step 6` loop? You never use `j`.

Comment: @BigBen my bad, i think you can ignore that part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You actually don't need the column letter. You can just use the column number within `Cells`.

2) You need to loop through each individual cell in the header row to test if its value is equal to `"Vbd"`.

Try something like the following:

```
 Dim i as Long
 For i = 1 to LastColumn
     With sht
         If .Cells(1, i).Value = "Vbd" Then
             Set rngToAbs = .Range(.Cells(2, i), .Cells(LastRow, i))
             rngToAbs.Value = .Evaluate("=abs(" & rngToAbs.Address & ")")
         End If
     End With
 Next
```

Full code:

```
Sub testing()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")

    Dim lastColumn As Long
    lastColumn = sht.Cells(1, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To lastColumn
        With sht
            If .Cells(1, i).Value = "Vbd" Then
                Dim rngToAbs As Range
                Set rngToAbs = .Range(.Cells(2, i), .Cells(lastRow, i))
                rngToAbs.Value = .Evaluate("=abs(" & rngToAbs.Address & ")")
            End If
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

Please see [this follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59898059/why-do-i-get-different-output-when-i-used-the-same-code-same-data-but-different). Note that depending on your version of Excel, you may need

```
 .Evaluate("=INDEX(abs(" & rngToAbs.Address & "),)")
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206587/discussion-on-answer-by-bigben-how-to-make-selective-entire-column-absolute-numb).