# Why do i get different output when i used the same code, same data but different laptops for vba?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to make an entire columns of cells absolute when the cells are below the header "Vbd" and I faced this problem: when I use the same code and same data on different laptops (one is excel 2010 and the other one is excel 2016), it gives different output. For instance:

[image]

Before I press the code, it was like this. After pressing it with the laptop with excel 2010, it gives this output:

[image]

However when I used the laptop that has excel 2016 it gives me the ideal output which is something like this:

[image]

The thing is I used the same data and same code for these two laptops (I have checked several times that both codes and data are the same) and I am super confused why the output is different. Below is my code
and the workbook can be found [here. (Dropbox)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qx89mhoeurktx7n/absolute.xlsm?dl=0)

```
Option Explicit

Sub testing1()
Dim i As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim rngToAbs As Range
Dim lastrow As Long



Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
LastColumn = sht.Cells(1, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
 For i = 1 To LastColumn
     With sht
         If sht.Cells(1, i).Value = "Vbd" Then
             Set rngToAbs = .Range(sht.Cells(2, i), sht.Cells(lastrow, i))
             rngToAbs.Value = .Evaluate("=abs(" & rngToAbs.Address & ")")
         End If
     End With
 Next


End Sub
```

Comment: @BigBen yeah typo

Comment: If Excel 2010 is the problem, then one alternative is to do the `Abs` calculation in memory using a `Variant` array. If I have time I can mock that up.

Comment: At a guess the older version takes the top leftmost value of a range and evaluates the entire range with that value. The 2016 is smart enough to apply the evaluate to each cell in the range.

Comment: try: `.Evaluate("=INDEX(abs(" & rngToAbs.Address & "),)")`

Comment: Anyways guys i just making assumption that different excel version may cause the problem. As i am new to excel, that could be whole lot of things that i have not discovered yet which may cause this issue.

Comment: @ScottCraner Omg it works but why?

Comment: i mean the code @BigBen suggested isn't wrong when i used it for the excel 2016 version tho

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer provided by @ScottCraner but posting for future reference.

Change

```
.Evaluate("=abs(" & rngToAbs.Address & ")")
```

to

```
.Evaluate("=INDEX(abs(" & rngToAbs.Address & "),)")
```

The current version works because the formula is evaluated as an array formula, if you have the latest version of Excel.

Adding the `INDEX` is necessary for older versions of Excel to evaluate the ABS of each cell in the range.

Added this comment in the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59882694/how-to-make-selective-entire-column-absolute-number) as well.

Comment: I go to breakfast and someone steals my comment.  Just kidding.  I am lazy and do not care.  Good job, expanding on the comment.

Comment: @ScottCraner. My bad. I thought it was one of those questions that you had just moved on. This is an instance where working in the latest version of Excel has bit me in the butt.

Comment: I was teasing, I had moved on.  The last upvote on your answer was from me.  You know if I answer as a comment that I do not care if one takes it and expands on it as an answer.